# How to kill and restart the recursive function in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, knockout.js, settimeout

I am working on knockout js.
In that i have a recursive function which executes a function every minute. for that am using a timer every 60 sec it will execute also same will be reflecting in the UI also. 
In my case, if i try to assign or initialize a timer value(observable) which is inside a loop, it doesn't reflecting instead of reflecting it is added to the pipeline and that much time loop is running simultaneously.
In that case i want to kill the loop and again want to restart every time i am changing the timer value.

timerInSec=60;

```
   var loop = function () {                        
                    if (this.timer() < 1) {
                       myFunction()
                       this.timer(this.timerInSec - 1);
                       setTimeout(loop, 1000);
                    } else {
                       this.timer(this.timer() - 1);
                       setTimeout(loop, 1000);
                    }
                };
                loop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Please check.

```js
timerInSec = 60;

const Loop = (function () {
    let timer = 0;
    let timerId = -1;

    const myFunction = function () {
        console.log('finished');
    }

    const fnLog = function (tm) {
        console.log('current time = ', tm);
    }

    const fnProc = function () {
        timerId = setTimeout(myFunction, 1000 * timer);
    }

    return {
        start: function (tm = 60) {
            this.stop();
            timer = tm;
            fnProc();
        },

        stop: function () {
            if (timerId !== -1) {
                clearTimeout(timerId);
                timerId = -1;
            }
        }
    }
})();

Loop.start(timerInSec);
setTimeout(() => {
    Loop.start(timerInSec);
}, 500);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time. In my case, i want to run myFunction() every minute. if any changes in observable value timer() then only i want to kill that recursive function and again want to start with new.

Comment: ok, then you don't need to call fnProc recursively. you only need to subscribe your observable and call start function of the above code inside the subscribe callback function. I modified the code.

Comment: Actually, when i use clearTimeout(), it seems doesn't do anything, still the existing loop is running.

Comment: Loop.start(timerInSec);
setTimeout(() => {
    Loop.stop();
}, 500);

Please try with this code at the bottom of the above code. I'm sure clearTimeout works fine

Comment: This test code would print nothing. If clearTimeout does nothing, 'finished' should be printed.